# Why Kotlin receives such an UndeclaredThrowableException rather than a ParseException?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, kotlin

I have an `extension` method that converts string to Date in Kotlin.

```
fun String.convertToDate() : Date {
  var pattern: String = "dd-mm-yyyy"
  val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
  return dateFormatter.parse(this) // parse method throw ParseException
}
```

And this is the code where I am trying to catch possible exception.

```
    try {
        "22---2017".convertToDate()
    } catch (ex: ParseException) {
        // ParseException supposed to be caught in this block

        logger.error("Parse exception occur")      
    } catch (ex: Exception) {

        // ParseException caught in this block

        logger.error("Exception occur")            
    }
```

The `ParseException` caught in the last block that is where `Exception` is caught. But should it be caught in the ParseException block ? What am I missing here ?

===**UPDATE**===

I am developing an Spring MVC project. I have run the code in simple stand alone  kotlin program where it behaves accordingly. But in my spring project it behaves differently. I am giving the the full code, `Controller` and the `Service` layer.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER','ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN','ADMIN')")
fun postAttendance(@RequestBody attendanceJson: AttendanceJsonWrapper,
                   request: HttpServletRequest): ResponseEntity<*> {
    val organization = getOrganizationFromSession(request)
    try {
        val attendanceBook: AttendanceBook = attendanceService.post(attendanceJson, organization.id!!)
        logger.info("Post successfully attendance book {}", attendanceBook)
    } catch (ex: SameDateAttendanceException) {
        logger.error("Duplicate attendance entry found at date [{}]", attendanceJson.date, attendanceJson.classId)
        return responseConflict(attendanceJson)
    } catch (ex: java.text.ParseException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        logger.error("Parse exception occur")
        return responseError(ErrorObject(
                attendanceJson,
                "date",
                Constants.INVALID_DATE_FORMAT,
                Constants.EXPECTED_DATE_FORMAT))
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        logger.error("Exception occur")
        if (ex.cause is ParseException) {
            logger.info("What the hell is happening")
        }
    return responseOK(attendanceJson)
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
open class AttendanceService constructor(val attendanceRepository: AttendanceRepository) {
@Transactional
open fun post(attendanceJsonWrapper: AttendanceJsonWrapper, orgId: Long): AttendanceBook {
    // ParseException should thrown from this line.
    val _attendanceDate = attendanceJsonWrapper.date.convertToDate()
    // Other logic goes here
    return attendanceRepository.save(attendanceBook)
}
}
```

**Log**

for given input `28--2017` from front end following log produced.

```
2017-06-28 02:36:52.942 ERROR 4632 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.l.c.rest.AttendanceRestController      : Exception occur
2017-06-28 02:52:32.485  INFO 2796 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.l.c.rest.AttendanceRestController      : What the hell is happening
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.lynas.service.AttendanceService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7b42c004.post(<generated>)
at com.lynas.controller.rest.AttendanceRestController.postAttendance(AttendanceRestController.kt:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28--2017"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at com.lynas.util.UtilKt.convertToDate(Util.kt:56)
at com.lynas.service.AttendanceService.post(AttendanceService.kt:23)
at com.lynas.service.AttendanceService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2b941a4b.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
... 103 more
```

Comment: @Mibac Yes. Those two are from the `java.text` package.

Comment: I just runned your code and it seems it doesn't throw any exceptions. I printed the output and got this: `Sat Jan 21 23:58:00 CET 2017`

Comment: "22--2-2017" is a valid string for the given pattern. try with something obvious like "foo".convertToDate()

Comment: Tried using foo but the exception got caught correctly (printed `Parse exception occur`)

Comment: @Mibac, you are right. my comment was for seal.

Comment: @seal try replace `ParseException`  with `java.text.ParseException`. there are half dozen classes simply named `ParseException`.

Comment: I have updated my Question. Please review the **Update** section

Comment: So your code printed only `Exception occur`. It didn't print `What the hell is happening?` right?

Comment: why don't you print the exception stack trace?

Comment: @holi-java I have added the Exception. Please review the Exception section. I have print stack trace in ParseException and Exception both block.

Comment: @Mibac Now it printing the `What the hell is happening`. Before there was an error. I have made change like `if (ex.cause is ParseException) {
                logger.info("What the hell is happening")
            }` . Before I was not extract the `cause`. You may review the Controller section again. I updated again.

Comment: The thrown exception isn't `ParseException` - it's `UndeclaredThrowableException`. `ParseException` is the cause of `UndeclaredThrowableException` though

Comment: the root exception is `UndeclaredThrowableException` not a `ParseException`

Comment: `UndeclaredThrowableException` is thrown when a separated *thread* exits with an exception if I'm not mistaken. It's much more likely that the `ParseException` is the root than the other way around: I don't expect the parser to split off a separate thread.

Comment: And the trace confirms this by the way...

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I could imagine that the service and controller each run on their own invocable. In that case you should catch the exception locally, not in the calling function, as there is a proxy in between - and that proxy gets any runtime exceptions wrapped in the `UndeclaredThrowableException`. I could imagine that *explicitly throwing* this or otherwise a checked exception may also help.

Comment: An ugly hack would be to catch the `UndeclaredThrowableException` and then rethrow the cause (as exceptions in Kotlin are handled differently than in Java)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes In Kotlin there is nothing like Checked Exception. Could it be another reason for throwing `UndeclaredThrowableException` ?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes also I could do like - catch it as `Exception` and then check the cause if the instanceOf ParseException.

Comment: You guys can provide answer for this post along with possible work around. That will give me chance to upvote :).

Comment: That would also catch `ParseException` or one of its friends itself - not recommended.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `UndeclaredThrowableException` is caused by kotlin. why? we know kotlin does not have checked exceptions.

The documentation of [UndeclaredThrowableException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html) says:

> Thrown by **a method invocation** on a **proxy instance** if its invocation handler's invoke method throws a checked exception

On the other hand, Kotlin can throw any exceptions but in java them will are: unchecked/checked exception and error.
we know almost all of the popular frameworks is created base on `java.reflect` package includes [java.reflect.Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

In short, when the kotlin function throw a java **checked exception** and don't declare the exception that it will maybe throwing.
then call a java [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) you maybe receive such a [UndeclaredThrowableException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html).

In java you can declare a checked-exception will be throwing as below:

```
//                v--- it is a checked exception in java
int read() throws IOException{/**/}
```

Thanks for @glee8e to points my mistake.
you also can throws an exception in kotlin, since kotlin don't have `throws` keyword so you must using `@Throws` to declare an exception will be throwing:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun read():Int{/**/}
```

---

let's reproduce the [UndeclaredThrowableException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html) in kotlin:

```
//throws a UndeclaredThrowableException takes the original IOException as its cause
// because java.lang.Runnable don't declare any checked exception at all
//                                                      |
//                                                      v
Runnable::class.proxying(::throwsAJavaCheckedException).run()


// throws the original IOException directly because java.util.concurrent.Callable
// has declared that it will be throwing a checked Exception
//                                                      |
//                                                      v
Callable::class.proxying(::throwsAJavaCheckedException).call()
```

---

```
fun throwsAJavaCheckedException(proxy:Any, method:Method, args:Array<Any>?): Any? {
    throw IOException();
}

typealias Invocation = (Any, Method, Array<Any>?) -> Any?;

fun <T:Any> KClass<T>.proxying(handler:Invocation) = cast(Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(),
        arrayOf(java),
        handler
));
```

### How to avoiding this problem?

If the function is wrote by yourself the solution is so simpler.
yes, declare the function will be throwing a checked exception. for example:

```
@Throws(ParseException::class)
fun convertToDate(){/**/}
```

**OR** write some gradle-plugin like as `allopen`, I named it `allthrows` here.

**But** you also can make some compromises. If you are not sure what will be happens in the frameworks like as spring,
 you should wrap your invocation into a helper method. for example:

```
val task = Runnable::class.proxying(::throwsAJavaCheckedException)

//  v-- the result return by catch-block immediately if no exception occurs
val result : Unit = catch(task::run).by { actual: Throwable ->
    val exceptional: Unit = Unit;
    //    v--- you can choose return an exceptional value or rethrow the exception
    when (actual) {
        is RuntimeException -> exceptional
        is ParseException -> logger.info(acutal)
        else -> throw actual
    }
}


val result : Unit? = catch(task::run).only { actual:Throwable ->
// only handle the exception don't return the exceptional value
    logger.info(actual);
}
```

---

```
inline fun <T> catch(crossinline block: () -> T): () -> T {
    return { block(); };
}

inline fun <T> (() -> T).by(exceptionally: (Throwable) -> T): T {
    return only { exceptionally(it) }!!
}

inline fun <T : R, R> (() -> T).only(exceptionally: (Throwable) -> R): R? {
    try {
        return invoke();
    } catch(e: UndeclaredThrowableException) {
        return exceptionally(e.cause ?: e);
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        return exceptionally(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about this - `when the kotlin function throw a java checked exception and don't declare the exception that it will maybe throwing (actually you can't declare any exception to be throwing at all)`

Comment: OK . But why not this "peculiar"  exception thrown in simple kotlin program. For example that code I gave in my post at very first.

Comment: @seal becaue your example don't using java proxy in kotlin.

Comment: Kotlin can explicitly declare something maybe thrown using [`@Throws`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/index.html) annotation to support Java interop. It will be a hazard for kotlin libraries targeting JVM if they can't specify an exception being thrown in the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your service is running in a different invocation context than your controller. As the service is throwing the exception you cannot catch it in the controller; it looks like you're calling the service directly, but due to code injection you really aren't. So what happens is that the invocation context (usually a thread) ends with an exception. This gets translated into a `UndeclaredThrowableException` with the original exception as cause.

There are two ways of dealing with this:

1. catch the exception locally in the service where the exception is generated;
2. catch the `UndeclaredThrowableException` in a separate try/catch and then re-throw the cause.

The first option should be preferred but requires you to handle the exception in the service. The second one looks too much like a hack to me, but it doesn't require setting up the exception handling in the service instead of the controller.

Comment: I may have several exception in service layer, DAO layer like SQLException, IOException, many custom exception. And I am catching those exception from controller  or  `ControllerAdvice`. What would be the best practice to handle this scenario ? Your given Option 1 or Option 2 ?

Comment: Although I have little experience with such a server setup, I would prefer fail fast - the more locally you can handle exceptions the better. That said, you may have to catch an exception at the controller anyway. The best thing to do is probably to catch specific excpetions locally and then catch a service specific exception at the controller. As always: think of what **you** want to do with the exception when it is thrown. Then the solution should come to you automatically.