# Kotlin EJB with Java Interface throw UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: ejb, kotlin

**Java interface:**

```
public interface IUserSettingManager {

        UserSettingApi updateSetting(Long userId, UserSetting userSettingNew) throws FailUpdateUserSettingException;
    }
```

**Kotlin ejb:**

```
@Stateless

@Local(IUserSettingManager::class)

open class UserSettingManager : DataManager(), IUserSettingManager {

    private companion object {
        private val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSettingManager::class.java)
    }

        @Throws(FailUpdateUserSettingException::class)
        private fun validate(userSetting: UserSetting) {
            if (userSetting.avatar?.length ?: 0 > DBConstant.UUID_VARCHAR_SIZE) {
                throw FailUpdateUserSettingException("avatar length")
            }
        }

        @Throws(FailUpdateUserSettingException::class)
        override fun updateSetting(userId: Long, userSettingNew: UserSetting): UserSettingApi {
            val logger = LOG.silentEnter("updateSetting")

            try {
                validate(userSettingNew)

                .....

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                val msg = "userId:$userId, user setting:$userSettingNew"

                when (ex) {
                    is FailUpdateUserSettingException -> {
                        logger.debug("$msg, ex:$ex")
                        throw ex
                    }
                    else -> {
                        logger.error(msg, ex)
                        throw FailUpdateUserSettingException(ex.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Java class with Exception:**

public class FailUpdateUserSettingException extends Exception {

```
        public FailUpdateUserSettingException() {
this(error);

    }
```

}

**When try call ejb with incorrect data, get exception UndeclaredThrowableException, and as result transaction rolled**

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-10.0.0.Final.jar:10.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254) [wildfly-ejb3-10.0.0.Final.jar:10.0.0.Final]
    ... 137 more
Caused by: com.pay.utils.shared.exception.user.FailUpdateUserSettingException: Fail update user setting. avatar length
    at com.pay.manager.UserSettingManager.validate(UserSettingManager.kt:xx)
    at com.pay.manager.UserSettingManager.updateSetting(UserSettingManager.kt:xx)
    at com.pay.manager.UserSettingManager.updateSetting(UserSettingManager.kt:xx)


.....
```

**result**

javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Comment: Related: [Why Kotlin receives such an UndeclaredThrowableException rather than a ParseException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788906/why-kotlin-receives-such-an-undeclaredthrowableexception-rather-than-a-parseexce/44790753#44790753)

Comment: How to avoiding this problem?

If the function is wrote by yourself the solution is so simpler. yes, declare the function will be throwing a checked exception. for example:

@Throws(ParseException::class)
fun convertToDate(){/**/}


**not work for me**

Comment: why didn't works for you?

Comment: fun validate throw UndeclaredThrowableException, though i write @Throws anotation

Comment: you should notice the `UndeclaredThrowableException` is thrown by jboss rather than your code, which means your code is ok.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Due to remote call, the exception is thrown by container so you can't handle it, you can try to declare `FailUpdateUserSettingException` as an unchecked exception, or use the utility method `catch{}.only{ex -> when(ex){is FailUpdateUserSettingException}}` in my answer to capture the actual exception.

Comment: It's easier to give up kotlin

Comment: yeah, my primary program language still is Java, Kotlin is my toy or a language for writing test only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any remote method invocation nor any serialization, which are common causes of this type of problem, but could it be a class-loader issue? That the class when instantiated by the Kotlin code is loaded from a different classloader, than the class as checked by JBoss, and that therefore it's seen as an unrecognized throwable?

I'm not sure how to check. Classloader policy in the EJB container perhaps - parent-first vs parent-last?

What is the behaviour if you replace the Kotlin code with a Java version that will always just throw that exception from the private validate() method, just to see if that makes a difference?

What JDK version, what Kotlin version, and what JBoss version do you use?

Comment: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final), java version "1.8.0_91, kotlin 1.0.6

Comment: Both your Java version and Kotlin version are out of date. I suggest updating to at least Kotlin 1.1.4

Did you try replacing the code with a Java class, as I suggested? Does that have similar issues?

Comment: and if change ejb interface from java to kotlin

Comment: If you suspect that there's an issue with Kotlin and how it implements Java interfaces, please first upgrade to Kotlin 1.1.4 to see if it solves the issue, and if that doesn't, then please create a minimal example in code that demonstrates the issue, as self contained project with minimal examples, so it can be more easily investigated by the Kotlin team at IntelliJ.

Comment: Kotlin 1.1.4 did not help

Comment: Then please on the Kotlin discussion forum where I found the link to this question, submit as followup the most minimal example you can build for reproducing the issue, preferably without dependencies on anything JBoss or J2EE related, or possible.